# Edit url for non static (website) s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created a S3 bucket named "test.download.abc.com". The purpose of this bucket is to simply serve the executables (exes) when a user clicks on a link [Download](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test.download.abc.com/MyFolder/MyClient.exe) to download the file. Here the href attribute as one can see is "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test.download.abc.com/MyFolder/MyClient.exe"

My intention here is to change the url that the user sees on hover to "http://test.download.abc.com/MyFolder/MyClient.exe" - one way of achieveing it is to have this url on the href and redirect it to the download file on click- which is working.

I would like to know if there is any record set "Cname" or "Alias" that I can create on the "Route 53" of AWS to achieve the same. I read about virtual hosting articles for which the bucket needs to be configured as a static site- which doesn't seem right for my purpose in addition to not having default site page. What is the right approach for me to achieve the same? Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here is deceptively simple.

All you need to do is set up the hostname in your DNS servers as a CNAME referencing the bucket's REST endpoint virtual hostname.

For a bucket named "bucket.example.com," in the "example.com" DNS zone, add:

```
bucket  IN  CNAME  bucket.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com.
```

> [...] the bucket for the request is the lowercase value of the `Host` header, and the key for the request is the Request-URI. This interpretation is useful when you have registered the same DNS name as your bucket name and have configured that name to be a CNAME alias for Amazon S3

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html

This is *not* the same as static web site hosting.  It's using a CNAME to reference the REST endpoint of the bucket directly.  This, of course, only works for subdomains, since a CNAME doesn't belong at the apex of a domain.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to go the static site route, you can setup a cloudfront distribution that serves the content of your s3 bucket, and then setup a custom name.

More here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html

> In CloudFront, an alternate domain name, also known as a CNAME, lets
>   you use your own domain name (for example, www.example.com) for links
>   to your objects instead of using the domain name that CloudFront
>   assigns to your distribution. Both web and RTMP distributions support
>   alternate domain names.
>
> When you create a distribution, CloudFront returns a domain name for
>   the distribution, for example:
>
> d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net
>
> When you use the CloudFront domain name for your objects, the URL for
>   an object called /images/image.jpg is:
>
> http://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net/images/image.jpg
>
> If you want to use your own domain name, such as www.example.com,
>   instead of the cloudfront.net domain name that CloudFront assigned to
>   your distribution, you can add an alternate domain name to your
>   distribution for www.example.com. You can then use the following URL
>   for /images/image.jpg:
>
> http://www.example.com/images/image.jpg

Comment: -Your explanation and the doc links is very helpful. Thank you Sir. Looks like cloud front costs more for the small purpose. Is it possible for me to configure the S3 bucket as a site, without having any default/index and error pages and still achieve the primary purpose?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do it w/out cloudfront. See if this blog article helps: http://carltonbale.com/how-to-alias-a-domain-name-or-sub-domain-to-amazon-s3/

Comment: Can't help but wonder if https complains about the cert with SSL enabled, or what one has to also do to get the same cert to cloudfront or if that's automatic AWS-magic and then you can't use lets-encrypt etc.?

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront is not required to meet your requirement, you can just enable S3 to serve static web content as described here

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html

You would also need to configure Route 53 with a CNAME or A alias record to your bucket

See this sample that combine S3 and Route 53 : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

Comment: Yes, but that is after I configure my bucket as a static website, which is not what I would like to do, because I dont have any other static pages (web pages) other than my executables. I dont have a index/error document.

Comment: As someone else pointed before, you can enable S3 Static web hosting without having an index.html or error.html document